# solana sign-offchain-message: what input format to use?

Tags: solana-cli

The Solana CLI has a new command `solana sign-offchain-message`, which has the following usage from `--help`:

```
solana sign-offchain-message [FLAGS] [OPTIONS] <STRING>
```

But what is the format of this `<STRING>`?  A message is generally going to be binary so it can't be passed in raw format.  I've tried base64 and base58 as well but these don't produce the same signature as when using the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the source, the offchain message is just converted to bytes with `as_bytes()` https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/669bc43bcd4ccdff79ba4d9738554a221201a994/cli/src/wallet.rs#L606.

According to the documentation, this function converts to utf-8 encoded bytes https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_bytes

Answer (score 1):

i think this video can help you find answers / example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHkOQeSr4MM